# How can I write a query with unwated spaces in my text?

Tags: mysql, sql, content-management-system

I am currently improving the search functionality of my cms so that users can search for entries by copying and pasting text from a web page and finding it in the database.

The query is simple. It takes the search term and does a LIKE '% text here %' query.

The problem is, I'm not getting many results and have figured out why.

In the CMS itself, a lot of the text that has been entered from MS Word seems to be double spaced. Such as

```
"Hello my  name  is James"
```

However on the front end website it renders properly, with single spaces, like:

```
"Hello my name is James"
```

This means my query is never picking up the database entry based on what is shown on the web page.

Any suggestions? Do I tackle the double spaces in the CMS (seems risky to me with so much HTML in there!), or can I adjust my query to cope with it?

Comment: You could use regular expressions: [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)

Comment: though u can use regular expression but that would be expensive, I suugest you to trim extra spaces while inserting in database, as they are of no use and your task of searching would be much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is only double spaces that are creating the issue, then just

```
replace(columnToSearch,'  ',' ')
```

when searching, or as @ManMohan suggests, before inserting the data into your table in the first place

Comment: Simple but effective. I'm getting the results I need now.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at **[`MySQL REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function%5Freplace)**

> `REPLACE(str,from_str,to_str)`
>
> Returns the string str with all occurrences of the string from_str replaced by the string to_str.
> `REPLACE()` performs a case-sensitive match when searching for from_str.

Comment: Simple but effective. I'm getting the results I need now.